# QSqlDatabse : the program has unexpectedly finished?

Tags: c++, qt, qsqldatabase

Everytime I declare `QSqlDatabse` connection in the header file of my DatabaseManager class, my application crashes with a message says: ***the program has unexpectedly finished*** ?!

If I put the declaration inside the source file, my application works fine.

1. Why is this happening and
2. how to fix it ?

**Edit:**

here is the header file :

```
#ifndef DATABASEMANAGER_H
#define DATABASEMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>

class DatabaseManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DatabaseManager(QObject *parent = 0);

public:
    QString open_db();
    QString create_db_tables();
    QSqlDatabase get_db();

    QSqlDatabase database;
};

#endif // DATABASEMANAGER_H
```

here is the source file :

```
#include "databasemanager.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>


QString DatabaseManager::open_db()
{

    QSqlDatabase db;
     db = database;

    QString path = "/Users/abubakr/Documents/workspace/Muasaa/";

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(path+"Database v.1");
    if (db.open()){
        return "Database is created and open, Application is ready ...";
    } else {
        return db.lastError().text();
    }
}

QSqlDatabase DatabaseManager::get_db(){
}

QString DatabaseManager::create_db_tables(){

    QSqlQuery query;

    //****************************************
    //create personal_info table
    //****************************************
    query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_Info"
                  "(ref_no NTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,"
                  "name VARCHAR(30), father VARCHAR(30), grandfather VARCHAR(30), mother VARCHAR(30), tel VARCHAR(30),"
                  "email VARCHAR(30), post_code VARCHAR(30), address VARCHAR(30))");
    if (!query.exec()) return query.lastError().text();

    //****************************************
    //create familly_info table
    //****************************************
    query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS familly_Info"
                  "(ref_no NTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,"
                  "spouse VARCHAR(30), father_in_law VARCHAR(30), mother_in_law VARCHAR(30), childern  VARCHAR(30))");
    if (!query.exec()) return query.lastError().text();


    //****************************************
    //create payment_info table
    //****************************************
    query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_Info"
                  "(ref_no NTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,"
                  "payment VARCHAR(30), payment_method VARCHAR(30))");
    if (!query.exec()) return query.lastError().text();


    return "Tables created successfully ";

}
```

Comment: little code would be better here!

Comment: Debugging does not show me anything ..@drescherjm

Comment: Is this on windows? If so are you using Qt that was built for your compiler version. You can not use Qt that was built for any other version.

Comment: ***Debugging does not show me anything*** You should be able to set your debugger to break on access violation (and other exceptions). Then step to the code causing the error.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror check the question-edit please

Comment: @drescherjm ... nice tip, thank you ..

Comment: There is no any relation between db object and query object. Your db instance exists inside of open_db() method only and query instance - inside create_db_tables(). You need to initialise db class member inside the class constructor or inside open_db() and than initialise query(db) inside create_db_tables().

Comment: Thanks @MaxFomichev .. it works ..

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple things wrong here.

In the ***open_db()*** method keep in mind how memory management in C++ works.  Nothing that gets defined there will survive. So for the following lines:

```
QSqlDatabase db;
db = database;
```

what you're actually doing is defining ***db***, then setting it to the value of ***database***, which is nothing.  You then initialize ***db*** to the values you want, but that doesn't matter because when the method returns that will all get destroyed automatically.  The ***database*** variable never gets set to anything.
In the ***open_db()*** just initialize the variable you've defined in your class instead like this:

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database .setDatabaseName(path+"Database v.1");
if (database .open()){
```

then in ***create_db_tables()*** you have to initialize the QSqlQuery object with the database you just created like this:

```
QSqlQuery query(database);
```

Once you do that everything else should start working properly.